# Making nested queries using the Django ORM

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, orm

Assuming I have a model like below:

```
class Region(models.Model):
    info = JSONField()
    number = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to write a ORM query which translates into a nested SQL query similar to the below one:

```
SELECT result, COUNT(number) FROM (SELECT jsonb_object_keys("region_table"."info") as result, number from region_table) pp group by number;
```

Is there any way to perform the above nested SQL query?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have gone through the docs, but haven't found anything useful. Subqueries are different from nested queries as far as I know. I'd like to be able to select from the inner query results.

Comment: subquery, nested query and inner query are same thing